# How to get F# quotation for a interface instance method?

Tags: f#, quotations

In F#, we can create interface instance by object expression, but while I'm trying to use attribute `ReflectedDefinition` on the instance method, then I cannot get the quotations. The method info is declared in the interface type, not the instance type.

Here is my test code:

```
module Test

open System
open System.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.DerivedPatterns
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.ExprShape

type IMyInterface =
    abstract Foo : int -> int

let createMyInterface () =
    { new IMyInterface with
        [<ReflectedDefinition>]
        member this.Foo a = a + 1 }

let expr =
    let a = createMyInterface()
    <@ a.Foo(42) @>

let rec iterExpr (expr:Expr) =
    match expr with
    | Call(objectExpr, info, paramExprs) ->
        printfn "info: %A" info
        printfn "reflected type: %A" info.ReflectedType
        match info with
        | MethodWithReflectedDefinition methodExpr ->
            printfn "%A" methodExpr
        | _ -> failwith "No reflected definition"

    | ShapeVar _ -> failwithf "TODO: %A" expr
    | ShapeLambda _ -> failwithf "TODO: %A" expr
    | ShapeCombination _ -> failwithf "TODO: %A" expr

let test() =
    iterExpr expr

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    test()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

If I run it, I got exception:

```
C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\TTTT\bin\Debug>TTTT
info: Int32 Foo(Int32)
reflected type: Test+IMyInterface

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: No reflected definition
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.FailWith[T](String message)
   at Test.iterExpr(FSharpExpr expr) in C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\TTTT\Program.fs:line 30
   at Test.test() in C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\TTTT\Program.fs:line 37
   at Test.main(String[] argv) in C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\TTTT\Program.fs:line 41
```

And I also checked the generated assembly with dotPeek, it is implemented as a derived class:

```cs
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)]
  [Serializable]
  public interface IMyInterface
  {
    int Foo([In] int obj0);
  }

  [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Closure)]
  [Serializable]
  [SpecialName]
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  internal sealed class createMyInterface\u004014 : Test.IMyInterface
  {
    public createMyInterface\u004014()
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
      Test.createMyInterface\u004014 createMyInterface14 = this;
    }

    [ReflectedDefinition]
    int Test.IMyInterface.Test\u002DIMyInterface\u002DFoo([In] int obj0)
    {
      return obj0 + 1;
    }
  }
```

So, the problem is, when I call the `Foo` method in quotation, the Call pattern get `MethodInfo` which is declared at interface type, which has no definition. So how could I get the actually implementation `MethodInfo`? and then I can get the quotation of the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem in a nutshell:

1. You're calling a virtual method through an instance of the type where the method is defined.
2. You want the quotation to contain a call to the method as defined on the derived class.

This won't work, and isn't limited to interfaces or object expressions:

```
type A() = 
    abstract M : unit -> unit
    default this.M() = printfn "abstract"

type T() =
    inherit A() with
        [<ReflectedDefinition>]
        override this.M() = printfn "override"

let expr =
    let a : A = upcast T()
    <@ a.M() @>
```

Fundamentally, the whole point of an object expression is to provide an anonymous implementation of a non-sealed class, so what you're asking for doesn't make sense to me - the compiler only knows that the object is some instance implementing that interface but can't know the concrete type of the instance and therefore can't know which (of potentially many) concrete method to use.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know, it is a virtual function. But a virtual function must have a way to locate its concrete implementation, otherwise it cannot be executed. And what I want is, I want to know a way to locate the concrete implementation by given the virtual function's method info, but not to execute it, I need to get its quotation. The use case is, I am trying to use this feature in quotation to code GPU code, which I don't want to execute the virtual funcction, but want to get the quotation and generate GPU code based on it. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: No, there is no way for the F# compiler to know the runtime type when the quotation is created (the quotation is created based on the syntax tree contained within it, which is independent of the runtime value).  You could do some hacky stuff at runtime to try to make it work, but it seems like perhaps an interface is the wrong way to do what you want - why not use a non-virtual method instead?

Comment: non-virutal has no problem, object expression is a very good way. And yes, I agree with you, quotation is in compile time, it has no idea on the runtime stuff. And I thought it for a while, I realized that I might need to check something in the objectExpr in the Call pattern, if objectExpr is a Value, then I can get its runtime type, which should be the concrete type. Thanks for your answer!